# How to remove mail queue from cpanel?

Tags: cpanel

How to remove mail queue from cpanel?

I want to remove only spammed mail. Other client data are never lost his mail data.

From example: in my cpanel one domain is spamming and It will be affected to other client mail service. So, how to remove mail frozen email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with following command.

```
exim -bp|grep frozen|awk '{print $3}' |xargs exim -Mrm
```

Comment: You can also use CMQ (ConfigServer Mail Queue). You can install it on your server and manage your mail queue. This has many options.